# Problema al insertar

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Hola disculpen tengo esta tabla  con un select dentro de cada campo

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
 <tr>
  <th width="30%">Item Name</th>
  <th width="10%">Item Code</th>
  <th width="45%">Description</th>
  <th width="10%">Price</th>
  <th width="5%"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><select contenteditable="true" class="item_name" >
    <option> Elija asignacion academica</option>
    <option  value="elige">elige</option>
    <option  value="elige2">elige2</option>
  </select>
</td>
  <td>
    <select  contenteditable="true" class="item_code">
      <option> Elija Tema </option>
    <option   value="nombre">juan</option>
    <option   value="color">azul</option>
  </select>
</td>
  <td>
    <select  contenteditacble="true" class="item_desc">
      <option >Elija asignacion </option>
    <option   value="talla">G</option>
    <option   value="largo">12</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="item_price" value="DURF060810MCHXDRA2">
  </select>
  </td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

y un jquery que debe tomar el valor que se seleccione

```
  $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_name = [];
  var item_code = [];
  var item_desc = [];
  var item_price = [];
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
  item_name.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_code').each(function(){
   item_code.push($(this).text());
   });
   $('.item_desc').each(function(){
   item_desc.push($(this).text());
   });
   $('.item_price').each(function(){
   item_price.push($(this).text());
   });
   $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, item_desc:item_desc, 
   item_price:item_price},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
    $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
    }
    });
    });
```

y este funciona inserta los datos en la base de datos pero  inserta todos los datos del select por ejemplo en el primer select escojo elije 2 , del segundo elijo juan y del tercero elijo G y lo que hace es insertar todos las opciones del select 1 , el select 2 y el 3 en un solo registro . y solo quiero que se registre el que se seleccione.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estás tomando todos los `<option>` de cada `<select>` en vez de los seleccionados, debería quedar de esta manera:

```
  $('#save').click(function(){
     var item_name = $('.item_name option:selected').text();
     var item_code = $('.item_code option:selected').text();
     var item_desc = $('.item_desc option:selected').text();
     var item_price = $('.item_name option:selected').text();

     $.ajax({
         url:"insert.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, item_desc:item_desc, 
               item_price:item_price},
         success:function(data){
             alert(data);
             $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
             for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
             {
                 $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
             }
             fetch_item_data();
          }
      });
  });
```